# Displaying text & images inline together

Tags: html, css

I've searched and searched, and I couldn't find a solution. I added an image into my navigation (my logo) and it is pushing the text down below the image, instead of displaying inline. How can I fix that?
[image: screenshot of problem]

Here is the css for the navigation:

```
header.container>.container--content>.container--navigation>li>a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1E7194;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<header class="container">
<div class="container--content vertical center">
  <div class="container--navigation">
    <li><a id='1' href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <img src="logo.png">
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

How can I get these two elements to display inline?

Comment: @sdcr http://criesval.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing so. [One solution](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/vertical-alignment-for-a-list-item/4075):

```
header.container>.container--content>.container--navigation>li>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container--navigation">
  <li><a id="1" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/90x90/000/fff"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
</div>
```

View Result Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image into `<li>`:

```
<li><img src="logo.png"></li>
```

Remove this style from your CSS:

```
header.container {
    height: 10%;
}
```

Then adjust the position of the logo if you need.

Answer (score 1):

you may set top with some appropriate negative value and position relative, but this may put some gap from bottom, see this [quiz site](http://sqrt.in) testimonial section, it will appear something same.